# How do I draw a line between circles in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a complex problem(to me) where i have 5 circles arranged as such and I want to draw a line from each of the outer circles to the centre circle

so every circle should have a line going from the centre of the circle to the centre of the circle with the house icon in the centre

Heres the view

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String selectedString = "";
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: AppDrawer(),
        body: Container(
          color: Color(0xFF191D3F),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                HomeTopBar(username: "User001"),
                Flexible(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTapDown: (details) {
                            final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                            final x = tapPosition.dx;
                            final y = tapPosition.dy;
                            print("Top");
                            print("x :$x");
                            print("y :$y");
                          },
                          child: CircleIconWidget(
                            width: 100,
                            imagePath: 'Assets/solarIcon-Live.png',
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            labelText: '100 W',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTapDown: (details) {
                                  final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                                  final x = tapPosition.dx;
                                  final y = tapPosition.dy;
                                  print("Top Left");
                                  print("x :$x");
                                  print("y :$y");
                                },
                                child: CircleIconWidget(
                                  width: 100,
                                  imagePath: 'Assets/EVChargerIcon-Live.png',
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  labelText: '100 W',
                                ),
                                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => EVChargerView(
                                              number: 1,
                                            ))),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTapDown: (details) {
                                  final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                                  final x = tapPosition.dx;
                                  final y = tapPosition.dy;
                                  print("Top Right");
                                  print("x :$x");
                                  print("y :$y");
                                },
                                child: CircleIconWidget(
                                  width: 100,
                                  imagePath: 'Assets/EVChargerIcon-Live.png',
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  labelText: '100 W',
                                ),
                                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => EVChargerView(
                                              number: 2,
                                            ))),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTapDown: (details) {
                            final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                            final x = tapPosition.dx;
                            final y = tapPosition.dy;
                            print("middle");
                            print("x :$x");
                            print("y :$y");
                          },
                          child: CircleIconWidget(
                            width: 100,
                            imagePath: 'Assets/homeIcon-Live.png',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            labelText: '100 W',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTapDown: (details) {
                                  final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                                  final x = tapPosition.dx;
                                  final y = tapPosition.dy;
                                  print("Bottom Left");
                                  print("x :$x");
                                  print("y :$y");
                                },
                                child: CircleIconWidget(
                                  width: 100,
                                  imagePath: 'Assets/gridIcon-Live.png',
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  labelText: '100 W',
                                ),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTapDown: (details) {
                                  final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                                  final x = tapPosition.dx;
                                  final y = tapPosition.dy;
                                  print("Bottom Right");
                                  print("x :$x");
                                  print("y :$y");
                                },
                                child: CircleIconWidget(
                                  width: 100,
                                  imagePath: 'Assets/batteryIcon-Live.png',
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  labelText: '100 W',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTapDown: (details) {
                            final tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
                            final x = tapPosition.dx;
                            final y = tapPosition.dy;
                            print("Bottom Middle");
                            print("x :$x");
                            print("y :$y");
                          },
                          child: CircleIconWidget(
                            width: 100,
                            imagePath: 'Assets/diverterIcon-Live.png',
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            labelText: '100 W',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have made a widget to draw a line between 2 coordinates but am confused how(if its correct) and where to use it

my line widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LinePainterWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double x1, y1, x2, y2;

  LinePainterWidget({
    required this.x1,
    required this.y1,
    required this.x2,
    required this.y2,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyLinePainter(x1, y1, x2, y2),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double x1;
  final double y1;
  final double x2;
  final double y2;

  MyLinePainter(this.x1, this.y1, this.x2, this.y2);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    canvas.drawLine(Offset(x1, y1), Offset(x2, y2), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

many thanks for answering my question and helping me on my journey with complex flutter problems

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend doing all the widget painting inside 1 single custompainter, and implement a single gesturedetector to update the custompainter, you can check where the gesturedetector position in x and y is, compare if that position is inside any of your n (1, 2, 3... 5) circles and update accordingly, so you can paint your lines on top of the circles that you drew inside the custom painter

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more